# How are the pkgrel, extraver, snapinfo and minorbump fields of RPM's Release tag used?

Tags: centos, fedora, rpm, packaging, rpmbuild

The documentation for creating RPM packages in Fedora Linux [states](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Versioning/#_more_complex_versioning) that

> There are potentially four fields which comprise the structured
>   `Release:` tag:
>
> - package release number (`<pkgrel>`)
> - extra version information (`<extraver>`)
> - snapshot information (`<snapinfo>`)
> - minor release bump (`<minorbump>`)

However, I can not find any information about how to actually use those fields in a Specfile. The [documentation's example page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Package_Versioning_Examples) gives examples for valid formats for version strings, but not about creating them.

So how would I have to write a Specfile for an artifact with Version 1, Release 2, Minor Version 3 and Package Release 4 that is a beta (aiming for 1.2.3-4-beta)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields describe the structure of the release tag; how you construct it is largely up to you.

In your case, I’ll assume the upstream version is 1.2.3 beta, and this is the 4th packaging update (so your release would be 4, ignoring the beta part). The traditional approach would be to write

```
Version: 1.2.3
Release: 4.beta%{?dist}
```

or, with more structure,

```
%global rctag beta
Version: 1.2.3
Release: 4%{?rctag:%{rctag}}%{?dist}
```

Alternatively, [you could use tildes](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Versioning/#_versioning_prereleases_with_tilde); this has the advantage (in my mind) that all the upstream-controlled version components are part of the `Version` rather than the `Release` (which is supposed to reflect packaging concerns):

```
Version: 1.2.3~beta
Release: 4
```

This only works if you have never packaged any release of version 1.2.3.

Comment: Great, thanks! So the fields are never specified explicitely in the specfile, but given implicitely through the structure of the Release: tag. That's the part I missed in the upstream docs.